# Links to access phone features from browser

Tags: iphone, android, browser, hyperlink, language-features

I know that I have seen something like this in somewhere...But no remember where.
Does somebody know what are the features of a smartphone(iphone, android, blackberry) that I can access from a Web Browser?
In some place I had see a list of links that can access different features of the phones(too many).
I mean, I know some things like:

```
<a href="tel:PhoneNumber">Link Text</a>
<a href="sms:Number?body=Message">Link Text</a>
<a href="smsto:Number">Link Text</a>
```

but, is it there something like:

```
<a href="Camera:access">Link Text</a> ???? OR
<a href="Accelorometer:access">Link Text</a> ????
```

Thank for your answers!!

Answer (score 0):

For iOS, it all works via a system called `URL Schemes`. Checkout [this](http://handleopenurl.com/) website which even builds the right link for you in HTML.